# Combine and sum up 3 minutes record to a single row of record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which will record data every minutes. It looks like:

```
time_stamp            wh   
2013-02-01 08:00:00  1700    
2013-02-01 08:01:00  1600    
2013-02-01 08:02:00  1800    
2013-02-01 08:03:00  1700    
2013-02-01 08:04:00  1900    
2013-02-01 08:05:00  1400    
2013-02-01 08:06:00  1500    
2013-02-01 08:07:00  1700    
2013-02-01 08:08:00  1700    
2013-02-01 08:09:00  1800    
2013-02-01 08:10:00  1800    
2013-02-01 08:11:00  1400
```

..etc

I want to sum up every 3 minutes wh data and find the average every 3 minutes. 
The output will look like:

```
time_stamp            SUM(wh)    AVG(wh)
2013-02-01 08:00:00    5100       1700
2013-02-01 08:03:00    5500       1833.3333
2013-02-01 08:06:00    4900       1633.3333
2013-02-01 08:09:00    5000       1666.6667
```

it seems easy but i can't get the result i want. This is the sql query i tried:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(ROUND(unix_timestamp(time_stamp) / 
       (60*3)) * 60 * 3) AS rounded_time,
       SUM(wh),
       AVG(wh)
FROM electrex_0
WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '2013-02-01 08:00' AND '2013-02-01 09:00'
GROUP BY rounded_time
```

By using this sql code, I manage to get the time_stamp correctly but not for `SUM` and `AVG`. I realize it will sum up in another way.For Example:the `Sum(wh)` for 2013-02-01 08:03:00 is 5100 which it will take the data from 08:02,08:03,08:04 and sum it up.

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to get 5500 from:

```
2013-02-01 08:03:00  1700    
2013-02-01 08:04:00  1900    
2013-02-01 08:05:00  1400
```

It sums up to 5000, doesn't it?

Here is your query fixed to return correct data:

```
SELECT
  from_unixtime(ROUND((unix_timestamp(time_stamp) - 60) / (60*3)) * 60 * 3) AS rounded_time,
  SUM(wh),
  AVG(wh)
FROM electrex_0
WHERE time_stamp BETWEEN '2013-02-01 08:00'
    AND '2013-02-01 09:00'
GROUP BY rounded_time
```

Returns:

```
ROUNDED_TIME                    SUM(WH) AVG(WH)
February, 01 2013 08:00:00+0000 5100    1700
February, 01 2013 08:03:00+0000 5000    1666.6667
February, 01 2013 08:06:00+0000 4900    1633.3333
February, 01 2013 08:09:00+0000 5000    1666.6667
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e5d5/15)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it with variables

```
SET @VAR:=1;
SET @group=0;
SELECT 
    time_stamp,
    SUM(wh) AS `TotalSum`,
    AVG(wh) AS `TotalAvg`
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
        time_stamp,
        wh,
        @VAR AS Level,
        @group AS `TGroup`,
        @group := IF(@VAR = 3,@group + 1 ,@group) ,
        @VAR := IF(@VAR = 3,1,@VAR+1 )
    FROM electrex_0
  ) AS l
GROUP BY TGroup
```

### SQL Fiddle Demo

Output

```
|     TIME_STAMP                  | TOTALSUM |  TOTALAVG |
----------------------------------------------------------
| February, 01 2013 08:00:00+0000 |     5100 |      1700 |
| February, 01 2013 08:03:00+0000 |     5000 | 1666.6667 |
| February, 01 2013 08:06:00+0000 |     4900 | 1633.3333 |
| February, 01 2013 08:09:00+0000 |     5000 | 1666.6667 |
```